# Using MediaSourceExtensions in conjunction with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to record the audio and video using mediarecorder and play it using MSEs.
Heres my code:

```
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
let video = document.querySelector('video');
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
console.log(video);
mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);


async function sourceOpen(openargs)
{
    let mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    let MediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(MediaStream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' });
    var sourceBuffer = null;
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => 
    {
        if (sourceBuffer == null)
        {
            sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mediaRecorder.mimeType);
            window.sourceBuffer = sourceBuffer;
        }
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => 
        {
            let arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
        })
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.data);
    }
    mediaRecorder.start(400);

}
```

I don't get any errors but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I'd really appreciate it if you could point out what the problem is(I'm on firefox, if that makes a difference).

Comment: [Works here](https://jsfiddle.net/pkh2qbn1/2/), are you sure you don't have any error? (you could inadvertently have removed them from your console, it happens). Also, you could avoid the FileReader and use `Blob.arrayBuffer()` which makes it more digest to read. And forcing your SourceBuffer's mode to `sequence` might be a good idea too (https://jsfiddle.net/pkh2qbn1/3/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I didn't find the problem but I'm guessing it was because I was opening the HTML as a local file and not a URL. I used the live-server plugin in VS code and it works! Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you need a SecureContext to be able to use gUM  (either localhost or https://